# Factor Level is Duplicated Error in "ordered"

Tags: r, sorting, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset with each row identified by a unique ID x semester combination. I would like to sort the dataset first by ID then semester, but when I try to execute `df1 <- df1[ordered(df1$ID, df1$semester),` I get the following error:

```
    Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
    factor level [2] is duplicated
```

`length(unique(levels(as.factor(df1$ID)))) == length(levels(as.factor(df1$ID)))` and `length(unique(levels(as.factor(df1$semester)))) == length(levels(as.factor(df1$semester)))` both return true.

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: `levels` of a column would be unique.  Please show a ssmall reproducible example and expected output.  Also, please check `?ordered`.  I guess the parameters used are not correct

Comment: Change `ordered` to `order`